# Scala - merge Lists into one List element-wise

Tags: list, scala

I'm trying to merge records stored as `List`'s into one `List`, where only one column with non-unique values is a `List`, the rest of the `List` are single elements.

Below is the example of what I mean by it:

```
val list1 = List(1, 2, "abcd", 5)
val list2 = List(1, 2, "efgh", 5)
```

What I need after merging is something like this:

```
List(1, 2, List("abcd", "efgh"), 5)
```

I'm very new to Scala, so I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Will the lists always have four elements and the divergent ones will always be the third ones? Also, a **List[Any]** is usually meaningless.

Comment: All the lists are of the same length and always the third element is the divergent one.

Comment: It might be worth considering that this is challenging because you've chosen an awkward intermediate type here. Usually `Any` is can (and should) be avoided, and doing so might make the manipulation you're going for more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All the lists are of the same length and always the third element is the divergent one

Then use a tuple, it would be better model your data, it would preserve the type information and it would be easier to do the  combination.

```
def merge[A, B, C, D](t1: (A, B, C, D), t2: (A, B, C, D)): Option[(A, B, (C, C), D)] =
  t1 match {
    case (a, b, c1, d) =>
      t2 match {
        case (`a`, `b`, c2, `d`) => Some((a, b, (c1, c2), d))
        case _ => None // The other elements not where equal.
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for ((x,y) <- list1.zip(list2)) yield if (x == y) x else List(x,y)
```

- `zip` combines the two lists and gives you a list of pairs
- the `for` comprehension goes through these pairs. If both are equal it yields only the first element, otherwise a list containing both elements.

Your code might become simpler if you manage to keep your lists homogeneous, i.e. all elements having the same type.